# Algorithm to check if a vector is in a finitely generated monoid

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, monoid

Suppose we are given a sequence of integral vectors $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_m\in\mathbb{Z}^n$. For some $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, is there an effective algorithm to check if
$$\beta\in\mathbb{N}\alpha_1+\mathbb{N}\alpha_2+\cdots+\mathbb{N}\alpha_m\ ?$$
Here $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

In the linear algebra case we can use the Gaussian elimination, what about the monoid case?

Comment: The case $n= 1$, $m = 3$ is known to be hard.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup

Comment: [Farkas' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) can help trying to establish existence, although the negative case still involves solving a [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem.